# How i check cache for sites.google

Tags: caching

i want to check cache page for https://sites.google.com/site/unblockedgames333/ i submit my url and google but it's not show cache option is there any way to check my page cache ?

i try this http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:stackoverflow.com but it's not work is there any other way to check.

Answer (score 0):

Instructions:
In Chrome, open a new tab and navigate to chrome://cache/
Click on whichever file you want to view.
You should then see a page with a bunch of text and numbers.
Copy all the text on that page.
Paste it in the text box below.
Press "Go".
The cached data will appear in the Results section below.